# JavaScript expressions and replacement rules

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am new to JS expressions and my task asks me to *replace* a *string* in a *expression*.

> Use regular expressions to apply the following replacement rules on a
>   string:
>
> ```
> a => 4 
> e => 3 
> o => 0
> ```
>
> Output the result of applying the expressions to the string ***‘Leet
>   Haxxor’.***

My attempts are okay or off by a mile.

```
pattern = /[a 4] [e 3] [o 0]/;
pattern = /[a > 4] [e > 3] [o > 0]/;

console.log(pattern.test("L33t H4xx0r"));
false
```

Really need a good explanation of how it can be replaced yet exist in the expression?

Comment: What makes you think _replacing_ something would work that way with the patterns you have given as examples …?

Comment: Oh boy. Have a look at [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). *"Really need a good explanation of how it can be replaced yet exist in the expression?"* You cannot replace characters with regular expressions alone. As you already noticed, `.test` returns a boolean.

Comment: I don't understand why you need regexps for this. Is it some sort of requirement?

Comment: You are combining the idea of "replacement" with the actual expression search.

Comment: It states that "Use regular expressions to apply the following replacement rules on a string"

Comment: Can it be done without a expression?

Comment: It *should* be done w/o a regex. Not only that but I don't think this is possible with pure JS regex (maybe you want some thing like `sed`'s `s/` flag)

Comment: Why shouldn’t it be possible using regular expressions …? (Plural, the assignment does not state it has to be a single one.)

Comment: I assume you are supposed to *find* the characters which should be replaced with a regular expression. But a regular expression alone cannot replace anything. A regular expression is a *pattern* and you use it to find out whether a (sub)string matches that pattern. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
var replaceWith = {
    a: '4',
    e: '3',
    o: '0',
};

var str = "Leet Haxxor",
    output = str.replace(/a|e|o/g, function(char){
        return replaceWith[char];
    });

console.log(output); // L33t H4xx0r
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6JrPa/).

The regular expression matches the characters `a` or (`|`) `e` or `o` anywhere in the string (using the `g` modifier/switch following the regular expression's closing). The function uses the found character (`char`) to retrieve the replacement character from the `replaceWith` object.

As Felix notes, in the comments, the `/a|e|o/` can, indeed, replaced with `[aeo]`, to give:

```
var replaceWith = {
    a: '4',
    e: '3',
    o: '0',
};

var str = "Leet Haxxor",
    output = str.replace(/[aeo]/g, function(char){
        return replaceWith[char];
    });

console.log(output); // L33t H4xx0r
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6JrPa/1/).

The changed approach defines the characters to be changed if listed, or a range (for example `[a-e]` which would find the characters from `a` to `e` inclusive), rather than the verbose approach using the `|` operator.

References:

- [Regular expressions, at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace).

Comment: For completeness: could also use `[aeo]` instead of `a|e|o`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var trans = {
    a: '4',
    e: '3',
    o: '0',
};

var str = "Leet Haxxor";

var re = new RegExp('[' + Object.keys(trans).join('') + ']', 'g');
// or hard-code it as /[aeo]/g for IE 8 and below

var output = str.replace(re, function (c) {
    return trans[c];
});

console.log(output); // "L33t H4xx0r"
```

Now, you can put anything in `trans`, and the script automatically generates the regex you want -- a more robust/flexible solution.

Comment: I get a different output when I run your code: `"L3et H4xx0r"`. That's because if you pass a string to `.replace`, it will only replace the first occurrence of the string. If you want to replace all, you really have to use regular expressions.

Comment: @FelixKling Ouch, you are correct. I guess my first paragraph back there was too bold ;)

Comment: I mean, you could still do it without regular expressions by iterating over each character of the string and build a new string. But at least to me, this seems to be an inferior approach :)

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I agree. Regex isn't evil, I just (at first) didn't think it was needed. But this is the right place for it.

Answer (score 0):

similiar to rvighnes' solution:

```
var str = "Leet Haxxor";
var map = { a: '4', e: '3', o: '0' } //make sure your last name/value is not folowed by a ,

str = str.replace(/[aeo]/g, function(x) {
    return (x in map) ? map[x] : x;
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: The function will run for every single character in the string, which is inefficient and can get slow.

Comment: But now you don't need the ternary condition in the return statement, since `x` is guaranteed to be in `map`.